# Email Reply to New Case Comment

Tags: email

I want to implement an  process when customer recieves a notification on new case comment, he can reply to the email and a new case comment will be created (this can be done instead / in addition of log in to the Self-service portal and submit a new comment).

I know that SF support is doing this also, see below the screenshot of "To" when I'm replying to a new comment

[image: Picture:]

Did someone implemented something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard Email2Case should let you do this.

From reading, adding [{!Case.Thread_Id}] to the Subject line should let you thread responses under the same case.

http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000J2pBEAS

Comment: thanks @techtrekker. The only piece missing is replying (I need some kind of a forwarder), is it possible that contact will reply directly to SF? (similar to the screenshot above)